# Scope of the pattern match variables

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, scope

There is some type `Record`:

```
type Day         = Integer
type Description = String
type Name        = String
type PhoneNumber = String
type Year        = Integer

data Month = January | February | March | April | May | June | July
           | August | September | October | November | December
           deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Show)
data Birthday = Birthday Month Day
  deriving (Eq, Show)
data DatingDate = DatingDate Year Month Day
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Record = BirthdayRecord Name Birthday
            | PhoneRecord Name PhoneNumber
            | DatingRecord DatingDate Description
            deriving (Eq, Show)
```

And function, which filter these record by date:

```
getAssignment :: (Year, Month, Day) -> [Record] -> [Record]
getAssignment (year, month, day) = filter matchDate
  where matchDate (BirthdayRecord _ (Birthday month day)) = True
        matchDate (DatingRecord (DatingDate year month day) _) = True
        matchDate _ = False
```

This definition of `getAssignment` is not correct because of error:

```
warning: Defined but not used: `year'
```

Actually, it is kind of surprise for me, that `year` in pattern matched part of `getAssignment` and `year` in pattern matched part of `matchDate` are not the same.

So, where is the scope bounds of `year` variable started and finished? It happens because of `where` section?

Btw, this error can be avoided with some redundant numerous using of `(year, month, day)` variables.

```
getAssignment' :: (Year, Month, Day) -> [Record] -> [Record]
getAssignment' date = filter (matchDate date)
  where matchDate (_, m, d) (BirthdayRecord _ (Birthday month day)) =
          month == m && day == d
        matchDate (y, m, d) (DatingRecord (DatingDate year month day) _) =
          year == y && month == m && day == d
        matchDate _ _ = False
```

How can it be rewritten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope is the whole expression (including the definitions in the where-clause), EXCEPT that variables in a pattern always define a new variable binding.

Instead of reusing the same names, you should use different variable names in the inner bindings.

```
getAssignment :: (Year, Month, Day) -> [Record] -> [Record]
getAssignment (year, month, day) = filter matchDate
  where matchDate (BirthdayRecord _ (Birthday month' day'))
           = month == month' && day == day'
        matchDate (DatingRecord (DatingDate year' month' day') _)
           = year == year' && month == month' && day == day'
        matchDate _ = False
```

Reusing a variable name so that it hides a variable from an outer scope is called *shadowing*. GHC should warn you when you do this if you use `-Wall` (or `-fwarn-name-shadowing` to enable only this warning).

**Edit:** For your particular function, this is probably a clearer way to write it:

```
getAssignment :: (Year, Month, Day) -> [Record] -> [Record]
getAssignment (year, month, day) = filter matchDate
  where matchDate (BirthdayRecord _ birthday) = birthday == Birthday month day
        matchDate (DatingRecord date _)       = date == DatingDate year month day
        matchDate _                           = False
```

But you can't avoid giving a name to part of the pattern if you want to use it, even if only to compare it to something else.

Comment: Is there any way to suppress that `month` and `month'` variables?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you give more details of what you're asking for?

Comment: When I saw `f x = x == y` definition, I want to rewrite it like `f y == True` because of redundant usage of `x` variable. In that case I would like to use the same trick to get rid of `year'`, `month'` and `day'` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching has the form : Constructor binding1 binding2 ... where bindings just (and only!) allow to name a part of the value for usage is the right hand side. That is all you can do when mathing values in the left hand side.
In your first example you seem to want to constrain the match by bringing a bound name in the binding, but that will not work that way. See guards for what you want.